# Filterable select dropdown (HTML, CSS, JS) - Code directly copied from Codepen not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, codepen

I found a nice filterable select dropdown on Codepen, copied the code, and tried to get it working on my computer.

While the layout looks fine, filtering does not work locally.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

**Working original Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/marijoha/pen/zKjvEw

**My (non working) HTML file live online:**

http://select-dropdown.bitballoon.com/

**Download my HTML file:**

https://send.firefox.com/download/bd917213cd/#mwjZbZTfXNNv6I8FTW5TLQ

**My HTML files's code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: start;
          -ms-flex-pack: start;
              justify-content: flex-start;
      font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      background: #1D1F20;
    }

    h1 {
      margin-top: 10vh;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      max-width: 500px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.5;
      font-family: 'Open Sans';
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-weight: 800;
      color: white;
    }
    h1 span {
      color: #FF908B;
    }

    form {
      position: relative;
      width: 18rem;
      margin-top: 8vh;
    }

    .chosen-value,
    .value-list {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .chosen-value {
      font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      height: 4rem;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #FAFCFD;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .chosen-value::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #333;
    }
    .chosen-value:hover {
      background-color: #FF908B;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .chosen-value:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #333;
    }
    .chosen-value:focus, .chosen-value.open {
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      outline: 0;
      background-color: #FF908B;
      color: #000;
    }
    .chosen-value:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, .chosen-value.open::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #000;
    }

    .value-list {
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 4rem;
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 0;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .value-list.open {
      max-height: 320px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .value-list li {
      position: relative;
      height: 4rem;
      background-color: #FAFCFD;
      padding: 1rem;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
      transition: background-color .3s;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .value-list li:hover {
      background-color: #FF908B;
    }
    .value-list li.closed {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:300,400,600|Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">


    <h1><span>Styled</span> and <span>filterable</span> select dropdown</h1>
    <form>
      <input class="chosen-value" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type to filter">
      <ul class="value-list">
        <li>Alabama</li>
        <li>Alaska</li>
        <li>Arizona</li>
        <li>Arkansas</li>
        <li>California</li>
        <li>Colorado</li>
        <li>Connecticut</li>
        <li>Delaware</li>
        <li>Florida</li>
        <li>Georgia</li>
        <li>Hawaii</li>
        <li>Idaho</li>
        <li>Illinois</li>
        <li>Indiana</li>
        <li>Iowa</li>
        <li>Kansas</li>
        <li>Kentucky</li>
        <li>Louisiana</li>
        <li>Maine</li>
        <li>Maryland</li>
        <li>Massachusetts</li>
        <li>Michigan</li>
        <li>Minnesota</li>
        <li>Mississippi</li>
        <li>Missouri</li>
        <li>Montana</li>
        <li>Nebraska</li>
        <li>Nevada</li>
        <li>New Hampshire</li>
        <li>New Jersey</li>
        <li>New Mexico</li>
        <li>New York</li>
        <li>North Carolina</li>
        <li>North Dakota</li>
        <li>Ohio</li>
        <li>Oklahoma</li>
        <li>Oregon</li>
        <li>Pennsylvania</li>
        <li>Rhode Island</li>
        <li>South Carolina</li>
        <li>South Dakota</li>
        <li>Tennessee</li>
        <li>Texas</li>
        <li>Utah</li>
        <li>Vermont</li>
        <li>Virginia</li>
        <li>Washington</li>
        <li>West Virginia</li>
        <li>Wisconsin</li>
        <li>Wyoming</li>
      </ul>
    </form>



    <script>
    'use strict';

    var inputField = document.querySelector('.chosen-value');
    var dropdown = document.querySelector('.value-list');
    var dropdownArray = [].concat(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
    var dropdownItems = dropdownArray[0];
    dropdown.classList.add('open');
    inputField.focus(); // Demo purposes only

    var valueArray = [];
    dropdownItems.forEach(function (item) {
      valueArray.push(item.textContent);
    });

    var closeDropdown = function closeDropdown() {
      dropdown.classList.remove('open');
    };

    inputField.addEventListener('input', function () {
      dropdown.classList.add('open');
      var inputValue = inputField.value.toLowerCase();
      var valueSubstring = undefined;
      if (inputValue.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
          if (!(inputValue.substring(0, inputValue.length) === valueArray[j].substring(0, inputValue.length).toLowerCase())) {
            dropdownItems[j].classList.add('closed');
          } else {
            dropdownItems[j].classList.remove('closed');
          }
        }
    window.CP.exitedLoop(1);

      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdownItems.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)){break;}
          dropdownItems[i].classList.remove('closed');
        }
    window.CP.exitedLoop(2);

      }
    });

    dropdownItems.forEach(function (item) {
      item.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        inputField.value = item.textContent;
        dropdownItems.forEach(function (dropdown) {
          dropdown.classList.add('closed');
        });
      });
    });

    inputField.addEventListener('focus', function () {
      inputField.placeholder = 'Type to filter';
      dropdown.classList.add('open');
      dropdownItems.forEach(function (dropdown) {
        dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
      });
    });

    inputField.addEventListener('blur', function () {
      inputField.placeholder = 'Select state';
      dropdown.classList.remove('open');
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      var isDropdown = dropdown.contains(evt.target);
      var isInput = inputField.contains(evt.target);
      if (!isDropdown && !isInput) {
        dropdown.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });

    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Check your console - you have `Cannot read property 'shouldStopExecution' of undefined` error. You try to access `window.CP.shouldStopExecution` without defining `window.CP` beforehand.

Comment: You are right, the console shows an error. As I am new to JavaScript I am not sure how to define ```window.CP``` beforehand. Simply writing ```window.CP =  undefined;``` after ```var valueSubstring = undefined;``` seems not to work. How do I define ```window.CP```? And as an experienced JS developer maybe you can tell me why I do not need to define ```window.CP``` on Codepen. Thanks!

Comment: because CP stands for CodePen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just deleting all the `if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(*some number*)){break;}` and
`window.CP.exitedLoop(*some number*);` fixes your issue.

window.CP is an something CodePen made to exit infinite loops.
Codepen had a post about this explaining the function as follows:

> "The logic to detect a hanging for loop is simple. Possibly too simple. That number passed to the `shouldStopExecution` function is the loop identifier.
>
> `shouldStopExecution` keeps track of when a function was first called. If the same loop is called for more than 75ms we break out of the loop."

src: [codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops](https://codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops)

Comment: Sam, thanks for your answer. Seems like it's a infinite loop problem. Removing ```if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}``` and ```window.CP.exitedLoop(2);``` prevents the dropdown from working. (See here: http://select-dropdown-2.bitballoon.com/) I played around a while and—for example—removed ```window.CP.exitedLoop(1);``` and ```if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)){break;}``` as well. But I still do not get it working.

Comment: I'm sorry, just updated my answer, in your code on select-dropdown-2.bitballoon.com  I still see some .CP lines

Comment: I also see an error on line 224 where you didn't open the for-loop with `{`

Comment: Ahh! Yes, now it works. Very nice! Thanks a lot, for the code and for your explanation.